# SimpleLDAP and Drupal accounts

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have the [Simple LDAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_ldap) (7.x-1.4) module installed and it works perfectly fine with existing accounts on my LDAP server.

I need to use the read-only connection. In addition I need to create sometimes some pure Drupal accounts. I even can create these accounts, but after creation, I can not log into these accounts, nor view their profile pages /user/xyt, as long as I am not logged in as admin.

Is there a way in Simple LDAP, that Drupal first searches in the DB for the account, before Drupal checks LDAP? Why can I even not view the profile pages?

Do I maybe need to use the full LDAP module, to use parallel Drupal/LDAP accounts?